# how to spill cells in excel if I have two spaces between text

Tags: excel, cells

I want to split cells in excel. I have one column A with many rows and between the text there are 2 spaces, For example

**2 GABRIE 205.10  V3361  40.00**

**3 THOMAS 230.80  A1003  20.00** 
.
.

must be split into 5 columns.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Take a look at `Text to columns` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After using `=CODE(A2)` to test on the file you provided, those so called "spaces" are actually `char(160)`. Basically they are Non-breaking spaces that is common character entities in HTML used to make two words stick together at the end of a line.  If you are pasting a string into Excel from an HTML-based source, it is possible you will run into this issue.

**Solution**

Apply this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(160)," ")`  to your cells and modify accordingly. You will get the "same data" but different result. See image for reference.

[image]

After applying the formula, copy the result to a text editor(Notepad) or whatever you comfortable with. The copy back the result in Notepad to excel, it will auto split into 5 columns. (Actually 6 if the space  is considered).

[image]

Comment: not working, here my file:  techtacho.com/test.xlsx can you please try

Comment: Where is the data coming from? I tried the excel and it does not work. However, if I type out the line and it works. I suspect that those are not space but character that Excel cannot recognised.